# Removing Icon and System Menu from TitleBar

Tags: windows, visual-studio, mfc, visual-c++

I need to remove the system menu and the icon from the title bar of my MFC dialog while keeping the maximize, minimize and close buttons.

I have tried using SetIcon(NULL, TRUE), SetIcon(NULL,FALSE) hoping that this will remove the icon. However, this didn't work. The icon still show while a bit messy, I think the app just took the main frame icon and resized it.

Can anyone help me with this.. I'm using VC++ 2010 SP1

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The titlebar icon can also be removed *independently* from the min/max/exit buttons, by using extended styles (tested only on dialogs, don't know how it behaves on windows).

Paste the following code into your dialog's `OnInitDialog()` method and it should work:

```
// Disable default titlebar icon 
int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
SetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME);

// Update non-client area of the dialog, for the changes to take effect
SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

I have also unsuccessfully tried the `SetIcon()` method and many other proposed solutions/hacks and besides the upper (i.e. extended styles) none has been worked.

**EDIT:**

I've just stumbled apon a much simpler equivalent to the upper code:

Just add `DS_MODALFRAME` to the dialog box styles, along with `WS_CAPTION` and  `WS_SYSMENU`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729172%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Tried the extended style version for a WPF 'Window'. No effect. Not tested on dialogs.

Comment: The question and answers are solely with regard to MFC, so nothing to do with WPF, WinForms etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the resource editor, edit the properties of your dialog: Set "System Menu" to false. This will remove the WS_SYSMENU [windows style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of your dialog.

EDIT: Oops! I just re-read your question and realized you want to keep min and max boxes. My solution won't do that. This is an unusual requirement.

Comment: Allowing a dialog to be minimized makes no sense.  There won't be any window left in the application that the user can switch back to.  Maximizing it makes little sense as well but it least it isn't fatal.

Comment: I don't see how maximizing and minimizing a dialog doesn't make sense. And further more, I don't really see how this is related to my question?